# Servlet doesn't receive parameters

Tags: html, jsp, servlets

I have a problem with some servlet which doesn't receive parameters from jsp form.In servlet i have:

```
String sifra=request.getParameter("sifra");
String naziv=request.getParameter("naziv");
```

,but when i debug it on server it says that both "sifra" and "naziv" are null..In form i have:

```
  <br>
    `<form name="forma" action = "IzmenaProizvodaServlet" accept-charset="UTF-8" onSubmit="return validate()" method="post"> 
    <table>
    <tr><td>Sifra:</td><td><input type="text" name="sifra" value="${proizvod.sifra}" required readonly></td></tr>
    <tr><td>Naziv:</td><td><input type="text" name="naziv" value="${proizvod.naziv}" required></td></tr>
    <tr><td colspan=2 align="center"><input type="submit" value="Izmeni"></td></tr>
    </table></form>
```

and it redirects me to that servlet..Does anyone have some idea why this is happening?I tried to change method "post" to "get" but i get the same..Thanks in advance!

Comment: Instead of using String sifra=request.getParameters("sifra");
String naziv=request.getParameters("naziv");   Please try using  String sifra=request.getParameter("sifra");
String naziv=request.getParameter("naziv");

Comment: i put "s" by mistake..

Comment: And open firebug (or what you prefer) and make sure that the form is actually sent to the server

Comment: First off, your HTML code is incorrect and may cause issues: the character before the form tag, the spaces before and after the equals sign for the form's action. I assume your validate() method is not blocking the request, since you enter into the servlet. I would recommend calling the getParameterMap() method to see if anything's returned: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterMap()